# one way snyc sharePoint(07 or 10) cal to google cal

Tags: sharepoint, synchronization, google-calendar-api

A coworker wants to one way sync several sharePoint calenders into his (one) Google calender.

I'm not sure if its possible to directly link the two (all the research i've done thus far says it is not(at least in 2007))

I feel most conferable with c# as the tool to do this but im not sure where to start

My idea was to download the data somehow (maybe rss feed) and then format it to .ical and then use some sort of API on googles side to import it

So the questions before the court is

1) is there a fairly simple way to export calender information from sharepoint using the web ( its a hosted server so we don't have direct server access)

2) Where is a good example off using c# to import a calender to google cal ?

(If you think there is a better method please let me know that as well)
+1 for everyone

Comment: Do you have access to Outlook?

Answer (score -1):

You can link the SharePoint site to an Access database and then run queries.  That seems the easiest to me to get the new records etc.